# Lambda Calculus Grammar

Tags: logic, computer-science, lambda-calculus

So in a lot of explanations of the Lambda Calculus the syntax is defined in the following way:

```
<expression> := <variable>
                | λ <variable>.<expression> //abstraction
                | <expression> <expression> //application
```

This implies that an application can be of the form:

```
<variable> <expression>
```

which to me doesn't make any sense and it should rather be:

```
<abstraction> <expression>
```

Am I correct, or am I getting this wrong?

**EDIT:** see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Lambda_terms) for example

Comment: In lambda calculus, variables can denote 'functions'. Basically, there are nothing else only *lambda terms* by which we want to express functions and function applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x(\lambda y.\!y)$ is a perfectly valid lambda term. It's not a *closed* lambda term, but that is a notion that is usually built on top of this basic notion of lambda terms. (Though, you can directly formalize "lambda-terms-in-context" which is probably a better basis for many purposes.)

Also, something like $\lambda f.\!\lambda x.\!((fx)(\lambda y.\!y))$ is a perfectly valid (closed) lambda term even though it consists of a subterm of the form `<application> <expression>`. The grammar means what it says.

My guess at what's leading to your uncertainty is that you are thinking about beta reduction which indeed applies only to terms of the form $(\lambda x.\!M)N$, but all this means is for applications not of that form we can't apply beta reduction at that particular application. So, for example, $x(\lambda y.\!y)$ is not reducible.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. But what would the point of such lambda term be?

Comment: @Zonko It doesn't need a point; it's just something that can happen, especially as a subterm. $\lambda x.\!x(\lambda y.\!y)$ is a reasonable (and in some ways important) normal form. More compellingly, if we want to prove something even about only closed lambda terms we will, in general, need to also consider open lambda terms. For example, if we wanted to prove some property about a set of closed lambda terms including $\lambda x.\!x(\lambda y.\!y)$ (such as closed normal forms), it's very likely we'll need to deal with the lambda term $x(\lambda y.\!y)$ even though it isn't in the set.

Comment: Ohhhh, I haven't considered that. It just made *click* in my head, thanks.